# Adding a Dialog to the stack

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a simple bot that listens for a facebook event trigger (not a message)
When it gets the trigger, it should start a new Dialog (RegisterPledgeDialog) and push it to the stack. But I don't know how?

```
public class DialogBot<T> : ActivityHandler where T : Dialog

protected override async Task OnEventAsync(ITurnContext<IEventActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
       // How do i start a new Dialog and push it to the top of an exiting dialog stack?
       // The code below is what I tried. It starts the new Dialog but doesn't return to it after the turn

       var set = new DialogSet();
       set.Add(_pledgeDialog);
       DialogContext dc = new DialogContext(set , turnContext, new DialogState());
       await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(RegisterPledgeDialog), null, cancellationToken);

}

protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
      Logger.LogInformation("Running dialog with Message Activity.");  
      await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, _conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);          
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. The reason it doesn't return to the dialog is because `OnMessageActivity` is triggered when the user responds, and that calls `Dialog.RunAsync` on your main dialog.
2. Dialogs can't/shouldn't be added to the bot dynamically. They must be added in the constructors and then called with `BeginDialogAsync()`.

I recommend:

1. Understanding how [CoreBot implements its dialogs](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Dialogs), particularly the CancelAndHelp Dialog, which handles interruptions. See how [BookingDialog extends CancelAndHelpDialog](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Dialogs/BookingDialog.cs#L13) so that every time BookingDialog is called, [CancelAndHelpDialog checks to see if it needs to interrupt](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Dialogs/CancelAndHelpDialog.cs#L22)
2. In your ActivityHandler, call the normal `Dialog.Run`, instead of BeginDialog
3. Create a dialog that handles interruptions and/or events; It should analyze turnContext and if it sees the `Activity.Type === ActivityTypes.Event` (and whatever other conditions you need), *then* it calls `BeginDialog`. Be sure you use `AddDialog` in this dialog's constructor.

Comment: Wow, this makes a lot of sense suddenly. Thank you for taking the time to write such a thorough answer, I really appreciate it!